# Asp.net core delete button not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a view like this:

```
<div class="GridContainer">
<div>
    <div class="row gridHeader">
        <div class="small-9 columns">Member Name</div>
        <div class="small-2 columns">Date Registered</div>
    </div>
    @foreach (var member in Model.Members)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-9 columns">@member.MemberName</a></div>
            <div class="small-2 columns">@member.DateRegistered</div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@member.Id" />
            <a id="btnMemberDelete" href="#">Delete</a>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnMemberDelete').click(function () {
            var id = $(this).closest("div").find("input:hidden[name='member.Id']").val();
            var url = '@Url.Action("DeleteMembers", "Member")' + "?id=" + id;
            openMemberDialog(url);
        });
    });
</script>
```

The delete button only works for the very first row at the moment. If say I have 4 rows the other 3's delete button won't even register. It won't even open the dialog box. Is there something I'm missing here as the code seems to be correct to me.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does ID have to be unique in the whole page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page)

Comment: The ID is the same for each element because it is **defined** in your `@foreach` loop. You need a unique ID for each delete button (or simply use a class for `btnMemberDelete`).

Comment: Change the `id="btnMemberDelete"` to `class="MemberDelete"` because you currently have invalid html (repeated id).

Comment: Ahh okay, I completely disregarded that fact thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nhg7fvad/5/)

As answerd above you need to have a uniqe ID or use a class. in my solution above I use a class like so:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.btnMemberDelete').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
            var id = $(this).closest("div").find("input:hidden[name='member.Id']").val();

           console.log(id)
        });
    });
```

Also correct your html:

```
@foreach (var member in Model.Members)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-9 columns">@member.MemberName</a></div> // remove the '</a>' here
        <div class="small-2 columns">@member.DateRegistered</div>
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@member.Id" />
        <a class="btnMemberDelete" href="#">Delete</a>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a unique id for each delete button. Or you can give a classname instead of id to your anchor tag.

```
<div class="GridContainer">
<div>
    <div class="row gridHeader">
        <div class="small-9 columns">Member Name</div>
        <div class="small-2 columns">Date Registered</div>
    </div>
    @foreach (var member in Model.Members)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-9 columns">@member.MemberName</a></div>
            <div class="small-2 columns">@member.DateRegistered</div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@member.Id" />
            <a class="btnMemberDelete" href="#">Delete</a>
        </div>
    }
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btnMemberDelete').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).closest("div").find("input:hidden[name='member.Id']").val();
        var url = '@Url.Action("DeleteMembers", "Member")' + "?id=" + id;
        openMemberDialog(url);
    });
});
</script>
```